# How to kill protected process in wix toolset

Tags: wix3.5

Is there any provision to kill system protected process in wix toolset.
I tried everything.
eg.

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action='MyProcess.TaskKill' Before='InstallValidate'/>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>

        <Property Id="QtExecCmdLine" 
                  Value='"C:\Windows\System32\taskkill.exe" /F /T /IM platform-agent-core.exe'/>
        <CustomAction Id="MyProcess.TaskKill" 
                      BinaryKey="WixCA" 
                      DllEntry="CAQuietExec" 
                      Execute="deferred" 
                      Return="ignore"/>
```

or

`<closeApplication ... />` element
but nothing works

Thanks in advance..